# R forecast - How to plot only subset?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'm fitting a model with the R forecast package like this:

```
    fit <- auto.arima(df) 
    plot(forecast(fit,h=200))
```

Which prints the original data frame plus the forecast. This becomes a problem when df is quite big, as it's hard to visualise what the forecast looks like. I would like to be able to select only the last X points from the whole series (original + forecast).

Comment: plot(forecast(fit, h=200), include = X)

Comment: That's perfect thanks! Can you make it the answer so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can include X observations of the original series in your plot with:

```
plot(forecast(fit, h=200), include = X)
```

You can see additional documentation with:

```
?plot.forecast
```